# How to subscribe mutation changes of a store with multiple modules?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Using [vue.js](https://vuejs.org/index.html) to build a login page. In my project, I have splited my store into two modules (User、Info).

[image]

In the User module, the `actions.js` aim to handle some asynchronous requests (such as login、register), and commit correspond mutation.

```
export const userActions = {
  login({commit}, loginUser) {
    commit(LOGIN)
    axios.post(`${ API_BASE_USER }/login`, loginUser)
         .then(res => {
           const { token } = res.data
           if (res.status == 200) { commit(LOGIN_SUCCESS, token) }
           else { commit(LOGIN_FAILURE, res.data) }
         })
  }
.......
}
```

I knew that: [In Vuex, we can subscribe store mutations.](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribe)
I want to subuscribe every mutation changes in `Login.vue` 
so I can load a notification to tell user login successully or not.

`Login.vue`

```
created () {
    this.$store.subscribe(mutation => {
      switch (mutation.type) {
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
          console.log('view success')
        // load success nitification
          break

        case LOGIN_FAILURE:
          console.log('view failure')
       // load success nitification
          break

        case LOGIN_WARNING:
          console.log('view warning')
          break
      }
    })
}
```

But this seems doesn't work.
Is it impossible to subscribe specific module's mutations in a store which have mutiple modules ?

Comment: What does ` this seems doesn't work` mean?

Comment: For example：A user logined successfully， so the `actions.js` commit(LOGIN_SUCCESS), and I subscribe mutation changes in `Login.vue`, as you can see in the `switch` sentence, when `mutation.type == LOGIN_SUCCESS` prints "view success". But it prints nothing....

Comment: Do you use `namespace` for modules in store?

Comment: Yes, I wrote `namespaced: true`

Answer (score 0):

Since you use the namespace for the store modules, you need to consider it when subscribing. For example:

```
created () {
    this.$store.subscribe(mutation => {
      switch (mutation.type) {
        case MODULE_NAME + '/' + LOGIN_SUCCESS:
          console.log('view success')
        // load success nitification
          break
        ...
      }
    })
}
```